# coocox suspends and hits the break-point

Tags: microcontroller, c, embedded, stm32f4-discovery

I am a complete beginner in the ST micro-controller programming.
Intention was to evaluate the software set-up one and board functionality.
So tried to blink an LED using standard code [available](https://stm32f4-discovery.net/2014/04/first-time-with-stm32f429-discovery/).

ST evaluation board: STM32F407VGT6 based evaluation board

CooCox CoIDE: Version: 2.0.7, Build id: 20170510-2.0.7

Following is (Also highlighted in the red rectangle) the message shows when tries to flash the code.
Please advice, How I can rectify this issue.

GDB Hardware Debugger (24/11/17 10:14 PM) (Suspended)
    Thread [1](https://stm32f4-discovery.net/2014/04/first-time-with-stm32f429-discovery/) (Suspended: Breakpoint hit.) 
        1 main() main.c:15 0x080010de

[image]

I have to tired to add enough info here, please let me know any other information required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behavior if you start a debug session... you can use the icons in the toolbar (or menu/short cuts) to continue, step through the code etc (see the icons a bit right of the green triangle).

If you want to run your program, press the Continue icon (I think it's called that, or Resume). It is the green triangle.

Or otherwise, do not start the debug session but a run session. This icon also can be found in the menu (I don't see it on your toolbar).

In the debug configuration you can switch of the (automatic) breakpoint at the start of the main function.

Note that you can have a max. amount of breakpoints (you get an error before it starts otherwise, not in your case though).

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with this message. Your debugger settings are probably having something like "break at main" flag. It is setting a breakpoint in the very beginning of the `main` function, which you see is hit. Just use your "step over" or "continue" buttons to resume the execution.